# Errores JSP con Servlet (ERROR 500 -Excepcion y raiz)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Hola buenas tengo este error usando JSP con Servlet para un login de usuarios y no consigo encontrar el error, importé librerias..., el servlet.jar...cambie datos... y ya no se que mas hacer estoy muy frustrado. Tengo que entregar el proyecto para antes del miercoles...
Os dejo aqui los errores y muchas gracias de antemano :(.

Estado HTTP 500 – Internal Server Error
Tipo Informe de Excepción

mensaje Error instanciando clase de servlet [Controlador.InicioSesion]

Descripción El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.

excepción

> jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet
> [Controlador.InicioSesion]
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) causa raíz
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Controlador.InicioSesion
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1224)
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1696)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

nota La traza completa de la causa de este error se encuentra en los archivos de registro del servidor.

Codigo del Servlet:

```
 package Controlador;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class InicioSesion extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String user = request.getParameter("uname");
        String pass = request.getParameter("psw");

        Consultas co = new Consultas();

        if (co.autenticacion(user, pass)) {
            /*HttpSession objSesion = request.getSession(true);
            objSesion.setAttribute("uname", user);*/
            response.sendRedirect("Principal.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        }
    }
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Codigos de los controladores:
Conexion:

```
package Controlador;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    //atributos y configuracion con los datos de nuestro server mysql
    private String USERNAME = "root";
    private String PASSWORD = "";
    private String HOST = "localhost";
    private String PORT = "3306";
    private String DATABASE = "proyecto";
    private String CLASSNAME = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";//driver de mysql
    private String URL = "jdbc:mysql://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/" + DATABASE;

    private Connection con;

    public Conexion() {

        try {

            Class.forName(CLASSNAME);
            //indicamos la direccion de la BD y el nombre de usuario y contraseña con el que queremos acceder
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD); 
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
        }

    }

    public Connection getConexion() { //hace la conexion

        return con;

    }
}
```

Consultas:

```
package Controlador;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Consultas extends Conexion {

    public boolean autenticacion(String user, String password) {

        PreparedStatement pst = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            //esta es la consulta a la BD los ? es para que no nos hagan inyect a la BD(seguridad)
            String consulta = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre_usuario=? and contraseña=?";

            pst = getConexion().prepareStatement(consulta);
            pst.setString(1, user);//primer parametro usuario
            pst.setString(2, password);//segundo parametro a recibir contraseña
            rs = pst.executeQuery();//ejecutamos la consulta

            if (rs.next()) { //si es correcto usuario y contraseña devuelve true
                return true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {//cerramos las conexiones
            try {
                if (getConexion() != null) {
                    getConexion().close();
                }
                if (pst != null) {
                    pst.close();
                }
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Error" + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*public static void main(String[] args) {

        Consultas co = new Consultas();

        System.out.println(co.autenticacion("vlad", "1234"));

    }*/

}
```

Por ultimo dejo el index donde hago el login:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, charset=iso-8859-15">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/login2.css" media="screen" />
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin-top: 4%;
            }   
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="topnav">
            <a href="sign_up.jsp">¡Regístrate!</a>
            <a href="Principal.jsp">¡Principal!</a>
        </div>

        <form name= "inicio" action="Iniciar" method="post">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <img src="imagenes/logo.png" alt="logo" class="logo">
            </div>

            <div class="container">
                <label for="uname"><b>Usuario</b></label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce tu usuario" name="uname" required>

                <label for="psw"><b>Contraseña</b></label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña" name="psw" required>

                <button class="btn_index_submit" type="submit" id ="enviar" name="enviar">Iniciar sesión</button>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancelar</button>
                <span class="psw">¿Olvidó la <a href="#">contraseña</a>?</span>
            </div>
        </form>    

    </body>
</html>
```

Dejo foto de mi estructura del proyecto por si os sirve:
[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De nuevo muchas gracias a todos los que leais mi codigo, me hace mucha falta y sois de gran ayuda. Un saludo, Alvaro.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InicioSesion</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controlador.InicioSesion</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controlador.NewServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InicioSesion</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Iniciar</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Muestra tu web.xml ya que el error es que no esta encontrando la clase InicioSesion

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por mirar mi codigo, y te dejo aqui mi web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Arreglé el error importando jakarta en vez de ajax de esta forma:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.*;
```

Con esos imports y quitando todos los demás.
Por lo visto es tema de la versión de tomcat que no admite ya los imports de ajax.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada en un rato (o mañana, creo)

Answer (score 0):

Adapte este servlet que es casi lo mismo que tu servlet , adicional te comento que todo lo que haga referente a tu servlet tengan el mismo nombre . Puedes copiar y pegar ya que lo adapte a tu problema . Saludos

```
        import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;



    @WebServlet(name = "Iniciar" , urlPatterns = {"/Iniciar"})
    public class InicioSesion extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           
        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public InicioSesion() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            
        }  }
```

Comment: Perdoname Jhosep... no se como debería poner el codigo que me has pasado. Iria en el el servlet que ya tengo creado? Te dejare arriba los metodos del servlet tambien sino te importa. Perdon por mi inexperiencia me vino todo esto muy de golpe.

Comment: Asi , pegalo en tu servlet nomas y me comentas que tal te fue

Comment: La Clase [Controlador.InicioSesion] no es un Servlet, me da este error ahora y tambien un java.lang.ClassCastException: Controlador.InicioSesion cannot be cast to jakarta.servlet.Servlet... y muchas mas lineas. No se si quizas no puse bien el codigo, lo copie y quite los override de abajo que daban problema.

Comment: Te comento que mi api de servlet me vino por defecto cuando instale apache tomcat 9

Comment: Las respuestas deberían ser siempre algo más que un bloque de códgo, indicando cómo usarlas y por qué responden a la pregunta del OP.